# Help with proof that a set of compact spaces is a compact class.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I'm reading 'Measure Theory' from Bogachev and have a problem understanding
one of its proofs. First a definition: A set of subsets $K$ of a set is a
compact class if for any sequence $\{ K_i \}_{i \in {N}_0}$ in $K$
with $\bigcap_{i = 1}^{\infty} K_i = \emptyset$ there exists a $N \in
{N}_0$ such that $\bigcap_{i = 1}^N K_i = \emptyset$. As an example
they say that a set of compact sets is a compact class. To prove this they
proceed by contradiction so let $\{ K_i \}_{i \in {N}_0}$ be a family
of sets in $K$ with $\bigcap_{i = 1}^{\infty} K_i$ and let $\forall n \in
{N}_0$ $\bigcap_{i = 1}^n K_i \neq \emptyset$ then we can construct a
$\{ x_i \}_{i \in {N}_0}$ with $\forall n \in {N}_0$ $x_n \in
\bigcap^n_{i = 1} K_i$, no element of $\{ x_i |i \in {N}_0 \}$ can be
repeated infinitely. So far I follow the proof, however then the book says
that because $K_1$ is compact there exists a $x$ such that every neighborhood
of $x$ intersects infinitely elements of $\{ x_i \}_{i \in \infty}$ which does
not seem obvious to me. The only thing I can come up with is the following:
$\{ x_i | i \in {N}_0 | \}$ is infinite, $K_1$ is compact thus
sequential compact so $\{ x_i | i \in {N}_0 \}$ has a limit
point $x$, but htis only means that every neighborhood contains a point other
then $x$ in $\{ x_i |i \in {N}_0 \}$ which is different from
containing infinite elements. Any help with this (or an alternative proof for
this example) ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative proof, using the open cover characterisation: suppose $K_i$ $(i = 1,2,\ldots)$ has $\cap_{i=1}^\infty K_i = \emptyset$. Then define $L_j = \cap_{i=1}^j K_i$ for $j=1,2,\ldots$, then some $L_i$ is empty (and we are done) or else all $L_i$ are non-empty, and decreasing. Then $K_1 \setminus L_2$, $K \setminus L_3$, etc. form an open cover of $K_1$ (because the intersection of the $L_i$ is empty, it's the intersection of all $K_i$ as well!), and $K_1$ is compact. This cover is increasing, so the finite subcover can consist of one element only, contradiction (why?).

Comment: How do I know if $K_1 \backslash L_i$ is open in the subspace topology of
$K_1$, I know that if the toplogy is Hausdorf then compact sets are closed and
thus $L_i$ would be closed giving that $K_1 \backslash L_i$ be open in the
subspace topology, but how to prove this in the general case?

Comment: This is the case you need. You use that compact sets are closed so their complements in $K_1$ are open in that subspace topology.

Comment: In the original proof they go also further to assume that finite intersections of compact spaces are compact, which is not true in the general case, so I think they are missing a extra condition for this example, that the topology is considered Hausdorff or more general that compact spaces in the topology are closed.

Comment: They are using sequences so they probably work in metric spaces

Answer (score 0):

**Henno** has given what I consider the easiest proof. For the one in the book we have $x_n\in\bigcap_{i=1}^nK_i$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Now let $A=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$, and suppose that each $x\in K_1$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ such that $U_x\cap A$ is finite. Let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_x:x\in K_1\}$; $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of the compact set $K_1$, so there is a finite $F\subseteq K_1$ such that $\{U_x:x\in F\}$ covers $K_1$. Clearly $A\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in F}U_x$, so

$$A=\bigcup_{x\in F}(U_x\cap A)\;.\tag{1}$$

But the righthand side of $(1)$, being the union of finitely many finite sets, is finite, while we know that $A$ is infinite. This contradiction shows that there must be an $x\in K_1$ such that every open nbhd of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$.